# Why does my coffee machine's water reservoir have two connections to the pump?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps

[I'm trying to bypass the water reservoir and plug my Ninja CP307 directly into a reverse osmosis system.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/244258/5778). This is a picture of a disassembled Ninja CP307 coffee maker.

[image: Ninja CP307]

But, when I opened up the coffee maker I found there were two pipes connected to the same water reservoir (pictured above)! What's the purpose of this? It's a bit of a bougie coffee maker.

You can see there is some kind of flow rate detector on it too.

[image: Ninja CP307 flow rate detector]

And this is another shot of it from a different angle.

[image: Bottom of Ninja CP307 with pump]

Comment: `I'm trying to bypass the water reservoir and plug my Ninja CP307 directly into a reverse osmosis system` ... don't be too surprised when you come home to a flooded floor

Comment: @jsotola why would that happen?

Comment: think ... what is the pressure in your house water system? ... does the tubing in the coffee maker look like it can cope?

Comment: doubt if it is a flow rate sensor ... guessing it's either an index-of-refraction sensor (essentially just an LED and phototransisror w/ crude threshold circuit) to tell if inside tube is wet vs dry, or thermal

Answer (score 0):

One connection is the supply to the pump and the other is excess return to the reservoir.

Comment: That would make sense, but why would it over pump? it's all done electronically. And why would you run two sets of tubes for that? Why not have one connected to the reservoir? Is it returning water while it's pumping?

Comment: @EvanCarroll what happens if a sensor fails? Why do sinks have an overflow connection? It’s easy to turn the tap off right? So sinks will never get too full… except things happen.

Comment: Stop changing your comment - I answered the first version.

Comment: Just saw your response. You can only change your comment for five minutes. So when I changed it, I must have done it right away. Anyway, I'm not convinced this is a safety feature or to return "excess". The patent says it's a high pressure relief/steam vent. See my answer above.

Comment: As in after I had read and commented on the original.

Answer (score 0):

I think this functionality is best explained in the patent filed by SharkNinja, [*"Automatic coffee maker and process for preparing a cold brewed beverage"*](https://patents.google.com/patent/AU2019288555A1/en?q=(coffee)&assignee=SharkNinja,Shark+Ninja+Operating+Llc&oq=(coffee)+assignee:SharkNinja+assignee:(Shark+Ninja+Operating+Llc)). This unit seems to be the Coffee Bar in question,

The tube is explained in this plumbing schematic,

[image: Schematic for AU2019288555A1]

This means the black thing in the picture is a "high pressure relief valve" which has the return steam from the heater.

You can further see this explained here,

> [0073] In an embodiment, a pressure relief valve 52 is arranged in communication with the heating mechanism 50 and/or the second supply line 48. The pressure relief valve 52 is selectively operable to release the pressure therefrom by venting steam and/or fluid. **In the illustrated, non-limiting embodiment, the pressure relief valve 52 is arranged in fluid communication with the fluid reservoir 24 such that vented steam and/or fluid may be recycled within the system 20.** In other embodiments, the steam may be vented to the atmosphere adjacent the system 20.

If the system boils water it will produce steam. That steam needs to be vented a direction. The patent covers three directions

1. **Recycled back to the reservoir.** This is what happens in the unit above. The pressure relief valve just puts the steam back into the mix after the flow-rate sensor. This is probably desirable as the steam could condense and it's already accounted for in the system (past the flow rate sensor) it just gets pushed again into the boiler. The worst case the check valve opens and the steam exits into the reservoir.
2. **Into the atmosphere.** This is the cheapest solution, but would create excessive steam.
3. **Into the brew basket.** Because the patent covers a pressurized brew basket (perhaps for a later version that does espresso) that seems like the most desirable option but would require the pressure relief valve to be "selectively operable", increasing cost and complexity.

This still doesn't make sense to me though because the area where the two tubes are attached seem to be a check/relief valve, but the check valve only seems to protect water from coming in from the second line to the reservoir. It doesn't seem to protect the steam from exiting through the line coming off the pump. But I know what the intent is so I'll play around with it and write back.

### Experimentation

I wanted to see it in action I connected it this second valve to a cup that was empty. I ran it through a regular brew cycle, and a regular clean cycle and there was nothing inside. I put it in a cup that was a full when the other line was empty, and again, nothing. The tube behind the check valve seems to do **nothing** in regular cycles (it may be a safety).

Comment: does nothing... unless you over-pressurize it...in some direction.  normal cycles are not sufficient to make it do something.

Comment: @Abel I've updated with the note it may be a safety and this is just normal cycles. I've also ordered a water regulator to see if I can simply match the pressure of the weight of the water pushing down. I'm not sure if that will work, or if the regulator is exact enough but that will be the end of that part of the experiment (unless I go for an arduino with a solenoid valve).

Answer (score -1):

I’m trying to do the same thing with my coffee maker. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: This is a comment, I ended up using a float valve in the water reservoir

Comment: Kman, this does not answer the question at the top of the page.